# Installed second m.2 (nvme) drive. Now my OS is unbootable

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, nvme

I bought a new m.2 nvme drive to migrate my OS to. My OS (windows 10 pro 1703 I think) was/is already on an nvme drive but it was MBR (uefi) and I was having trouble updating windows (20h2).  My plan was to migrate the OS to the new drive and change to a gpt format. Well as soon as I installed the new drive the PC wouldn't boot (I literally just plugged it in (asrock taichi x399)). I have tried recovery options such as the "repair my computer" and fixmbr as well as bootrec commands fixboot (not recognized) and rebuildbcd (the requested system device cannot be found). I have removed the new drive and tried these options and it still wont boot. I dont want to give up as the drive has important work on it. I can see the drive and its partitions still and the files are all still there and I am able to install and run windows on the new drive. I just cant get the old OS to boot or any of the programs to work.

I would love to get the drive to boot, but if that can't happen the real question is how do I get my data/programs/saved projects/to work again. There is also a windows raid attached to the OS. I really dont want to lose any of it and I'm not familiar with trying to restore a raid system.

I feel like I'm in over my head a bit. Thanks for any advice. I'll try and answer any pertinent questions to the best of my ability.

(Ok so I didn’t realize I would need to say this. But I have checked the boot order. I have also unplugged all the drives other than the original boot. The original nvme drive is most definitely not GPT format. I believe I have been using the CSM compatibility to boot but I can’t see to make that work now. This is not the first instance of this windows OS. I migrated to boot NVME from a spinning drive.)

Comment: It’s literally impossible to use MBR schema while in UEFI mode.  Most NVMe drives require UEFI mode and that means GPT. Instead of submitting a comment you should edit your question with your original user account

Comment: You will have to do a new install. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible and Windows requires different partitioning. BIOS & UEFI Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations & 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Answer (score 0):

## Boot device priority

Go into your UEFI(BIOS) and set the boot device priority of your original NVME drive above the new one.

## UEFI pointers

If the boot order is correct but you still can't boot, then it could be damaged EFI system partition, or it's contents. It can also be the an invalidation of the UEFI entry that should load the Windows boot routine.

## Possible workaround

You could try installing rEFInd on a USB stick to circumvent most of the problems mentioned above.

See if rEFInd can auto-detect your Windows install and it's boot options. It may successfully chain-load the Windows boot routine if it wasn't damaged or over-customiewd.